Add character factor column in R based on integer in previous column?
I have a dataframe of hail events and their numeric related damages. I want to add a column (DAMAGE_PROP) that has factors of "yes" or "no" to indicate whether or not there was damage to the property as indicated in the existing column DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM.  With the code I'm currently using, I'm getting an "unused argument" error (levels = 2, labels = c("yes", "no")).
Can you assist?  Here's the code snippet, and the table of listed damages:
 AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROP <- as.factor(AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM, 
                              levels = 2, 
                              labels = c("yes", "no"))

table(AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM)

       $0    $250   $400   $500  $1000  $2000   $5000    $6000    $10000   $15000    $20000 etc.
     1163       2      1      5      5      4      12        1         7        1         3 

I also tried the more general code
factor(x = character(), levels, labels = levels,
       exclude = NA, ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA)

not using "as.factor"
AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROP <- factor(AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM = character(), 
    Error: unexpected '=' in "AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROP <- factor(AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM ="


I have also tried
    answer <- factor(c("yes", "no"))
    type <- unlist(lapply(answer, function(x) ifelse(as.numeric(substr(as.character(x), 2,   nchar(as.character(x))))>0, 'yes', 'no')))
    damage <- data.frame(answer=answer, type=factor(type))
    is.factor(AZ_HAIL$DAMAGE_PROP)
    damage

results:

      answer type
    1    yes <NA>
    2     no <NA>


You could say DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM > 0 which results in FALSE/TRUE then give labels= "no" "yes" which will be applied in alphabetical order.
> AZ_HAIL |>
+   transform(DAMAGE_PROP=factor(DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM > 0, labels=c('no', 'yes')))
    DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM DAMAGE_PROP
1                     0          no
2                     0          no
...
16                    0          no
17                10000         yes
18                    0          no
19                    0          no
20                    0          no
21                    0          no
22                    0          no
23                  500         yes
24                    0          no
25                    0          no
26                    0          no
27                    0          no
28                    0          no
29                    0          no
...


Data:
set.seed(42)
AZ_HAIL <- data.frame(
  DAMAGE_PROPERTY_NUM=sample(c(0, 250, 400, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 6000, 10000, 
                               15000, 20000), 1500,
       prob=c(1163, 2, 1, 5, 5, 4, 12, 1, 7, 1, 3), replace=TRUE))

